# Problem dispatching with google mobile analytics for iphone

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I have integrated Google mobile analytics into my iphone app, but for some reason the page views and events are not dispatching.

I put this into my app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching method (i've x'd out the UA string):

> [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-xxxxxx-x" dispatchPeriod:10 delegate:self];
> NSError *error;
> [[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/home" withError:&error];

This is the delegate method:

> - (void)trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)eventsDispatched eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)eventsFailedDispatch
> {
>
>     NSLog(@"Google Analytics Dispatch: succeeded:%i, failed:%i",eventsDispatched,eventsFailedDispatch);
>
> }

which prints out the message:

> Google Analytics Dispatch: succeeded:0, failed:190

Did anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: I see the problem, you're using xxxxxx-x instead of your Analytics account number!  ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't this be firing asynchronously and not caring about a return from the call?

Comment: Yes, it's meant to dispatch every 10 seconds, but none of my events for the past 2 days have dispatched (hence the 190 number)

Comment: @Eamonn I am facing same problem. I reset simulator content & settings but it does not solve the problem. I am using latest google analytics sdk. Can you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out all you have to do is delete the application and reinstall. Once you log one incorrect page view (ie one without a "/" at the beginning) nothing will upload to google analytics

Answer (score 3):

The Google Analytics stop sending data when you try to send a non formatted "URL", if it is not initiated with the "/" or contain some specific chars, it will start only returning errors.

The best thing to do is, verify that you are placing the "/" on the beginning of you URL and before sending, format your URL to avoid any problem, by doing:

```
NSString* pageURLString = [pageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Encoding it with NSASCIIStringEncoding, will format the URL properly. The same can be used when tracking an event.