# Cannot get Google Analytics API to register page views on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

I would like to gather usage statistics for my iPhone app using Google Analytics so I'm trying to configure it using the following tutorial: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html

I think I did everything they indicate in the documentation, and I get no error on the iPhone side, but I don't see any visits in Google Analytics.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self initGoogleAnalytics];
//...
}

-(void)initGoogleAnalytics{
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GoogleAnalyticsCode"]
                                           dispatchPeriod:-1
                                                 delegate:nil

    NSError *error;
    if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/home" withError:&error]){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription], nil);
    }
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch];
}
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the same answer that I put at: [Problem dispatching with google mobile analytics for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682380/problem-dispatching-with-google-mobile-analytics-for-iphone)

The Google Analytics stop sending data when you try to send a non formatted "URL", if it is not initiated with the "/" or contain some specific chars, it will start only returning errors.

The best thing to do is, verify that you are placing the "/" on the beginning of you URL and before sending, format your URL to avoid any problem, by doing:

```
NSString* pageURLString = [pageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Encoding it with NSASCIIStringEncoding, will format the URL properly. The same can be used when tracking an event.